# We all know about natural anti inflammatory foods but how many broccoli is equivalent to 1 Tylenol?

Tags: inflammation, anti-inflammatory

We all know about natural anti inflammatory foods but how many broccoli is equivalent to 1 Tylenol ? http://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/foods-that-fight-inflammation has natural anti-inflammatories . Reason for asking this question is how much natural things to take to combat inflammation ?

Comment: Tylenol is not an anti inflammatory drug, it is a pain reliever and fever reducer.